# Can we shorten s1.Equals(s2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)?

Tags: c#, string, comparison, equals

When I'm comparing two strings case-insensitively, I use:

```
if (s1.Equals(s2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) ...
```

I'd like to shorten this statement throughout my code as the `String.Comparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` is pretty verbose especially if you have to do multiple comparisons.

Is there a way to alias this so its picked up throughout an entire MVC project?
(I also have external classes I'd have to add this alias too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) for it.

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
  public static class MyExtensions
  {
    public static bool MyEqual(this String s1, string s2)
    {
        return s1.Equals(s2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make the equality comparer a private static variable, and use that variable in your methods:

In your class declaration:

```
private static readonly IEqualityComparer<string> EqIgnoreCase =
    StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;
```

In your method:

```
if (EqIgnoreCase.Equals(s1, s2)) {
    // ...
}
```

One advantage of this approach is that it looks symmetric; the other is that it wouldn't throw if `s1` or `s2` is `null`.

Comment: Sorry, had to remove my comment as that first line doesn't appear to work at all.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer Oops, you're right, I used a wrong type (`StringComparison` instead of `StringComparer`). It should work now.

Answer (score 2):

Why not write an extension method which does this comparison without case?

```
public static bool EqualsIgnoreCase(this string s1, string s2)
{
    return s1.Equals(s2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple extension method.

```
public static bool EqualsCaseLess(this string s1, string value)
{
  return s1.Equals(value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extension method:

```
public static CiEquals(this string s1, string s2)
{
    return s1.Equals(s2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

Comment: Won't compile, must be a member of a static class.

Comment: That's a prerequisite for extension methods, yes. Would you like a surrounding static class posted as well?